# Compilation error while sending function pointer of member function

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost scope_guard

I need to send the function pointer of a member function to make_guard function

I tried it in the following way:

```
class A
{
  HRESULT foo(int x);
  HRESULT foo_1(int x);
}

STDMETHODIMP A::foo(int x)
{....};

STDMETHODIMP A::foo_1(int x)
{

    boost::scope_guard xyz= 
    boost::make_guard(&A::foo, x);
}
```

But it gives compilation error:

```
E:\ThirdPartyCore\Boost\1_43_0\winx64\include\boost/multi_index/detail/scope_guard.hpp(103) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
        E:\ThirdPartyCore\Boost\1_43_0\winx64\include\boost/multi_index/detail/scope_guard.hpp(103) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::multi_index::detail::scope_guard_impl1<F,P1>::execute(void)'
        with
        [
            F=HRESULT (__cdecl A::* )(int),
            P1=int
        ]
        see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::scope_guard_impl1<F,P1>' being compiled
        with
        [
            F=HRESULT (__cdecl A::* )(int),
            P1=int
        ]

AGPSEngine - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Can any body please help me fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, `A::foo` is not a function taking one parameter; it is a member function.  I believe you want to use `obj_scope_guard` and `make_obj_scope_guard`, passing `this`.